# Почему когда я пишу неправильно ответ 1 раз, то когда я в 2 раз пишу правильный ответ, break не срабатывает? C#

Tags: c#

```
введите сюда код
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
static void slovo()
{
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();

}
static void slovo2()
{

string answer2 = Console.ReadLine();

};


Console.WriteLine("Здравствуйте! Это программа обучения английскому языку!");
Console.WriteLine("Введите ваше имя: ");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Здравствуйте, {0}", name);
Console.WriteLine("Нажмите Enter чтобы начать обучение:");
Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Стул - Chair");
Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Машина - Car");
Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Экран - Display");
Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Ты - You, Я - I, Они - They, Наш - Our, Твой - Your, Мой - My, Их - Their");
Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Грамматика");
Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Чтобы сделать утвердительное предложение");
Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Нужно поставить все глаголы и сущ. как в русском предложении");
Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Пример: Я люблю тебя - I love you");
Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Попробуйте: ");
Console.WriteLine("Переведите предложение на английский: Наша машина");
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
while(answer != "Our car")
{
    slovo();
    if(answer == "Our car")
    {
        break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Молодец, {0}", name);
Console.WriteLine("Для того чтобы составить предложение с вопросом нужно поменять местами, например will и you");
Console.WriteLine("You will - утвердительно, Will you? - вопросительно");
Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Попробуйте: Ты выйдешь за меня?");
Console.WriteLine("Подсказка: You will marry me - утвердительное предложение");
string answer2 = Console.ReadLine();
while(answer2 != "Will you marry me?")
{
    slovo2();
    if(answer2 == "Will you marry me?")
    {
        break;
    }
};
Console.WriteLine("Поздравляем вы прошли 1 курс обучения!");
Console.WriteLine("Это конец программы, потому что у разработчика скоро отвалятся руки");
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 2. [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладкой кода для понимания где проблема